# Contact Photo not being found?

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I have been searching throughout Stackoverflow and the Android official documentation about retrieving the photos of Contacts, and I just don't understand it at all. I am pretty new to Java, so I don't even understand what an InputStream does or what a URI is, besides a "Uniform Resource Identifier."

Because of this, I just copy and pasted the code from the Android documentation because I figured there was no way to go wrong with it. Well it turns out, every single time I try to open a photo, it returns null. Google sure did make going about the contacts pretty dang hard. Like there is so much to simply retrieving a contact's name, let alone the picture.

Here is the code:

`openPhoto()` function:

```
private InputStream openPhoto(long contactId) {
    Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);

    if(cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);

            if(data != null)
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Area where photo is opened:

```
...
InputStream stream = openPhoto(c.getID());
if(stream != null)
    Log.i("PHOTO", stream.toString());
else
    Log.i("NULL", "PHOTO IS NULL");
...
```

In the code above, the Logger always keeps logging "NULL" : "PHOTO IS NULL". So, **Why is the photo of a contact not being found here?**

**EDIT**: if you have an answer, please explain what is going on. I appreciate any answer, but I would like to learn what is going on. So far, this is still unsolved. So if you have an answer, just explain why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to retrieve bitmap image of the selected contact.

```
private void retrieveContactPhoto() {
    Bitmap photo = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));
        if (inputStream != null) {
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream); 
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null)
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```